# Check that 2 arrays of file names are the same

Tags: bash, filenames, array

So I have the following:

```
cat file | grep -E regex
```

which gives a list of lines
Now I also have a for loop the produces a list of files
So it is like I have 2 arrays.
But how do I check in bash if both arrays have the same content? My bash version does not support associative arrays (4.2).
Should I find another way other than bash or is it doable with bash easily too?

**Update**
I go over `for i in foo/bar/*` and record the paths so I essentially I have somewhere:

```
foo/bar/a/b  
foo/bar/c/d   
foo/bar/e etc
```

So I essentially just want to re-run the for loop and check that I get exactly the same outcome.

Comment: Using `grep` or `diff`could help. Add sample data to your post for more infos.

Comment: filenames can span more than one line, unfortunately. Do you have any insight or control into what generates the contents of `file`? Or can you declare an assumption/restriction that your filenames will never have newlines in them?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Yes no new lines in file names

Comment: Some sample data / directory structure might help understand your request, as "a list of lines" does not necessarily equal "a list of files".

Comment: @RudiC:I go over `for i in foo/bar/*` and record the paths so I essentially I have somewhere: `foo/bar/a/b foo/bar/c/d foo/bar/e` etc. So I essentially just want to re-run the for loop and check that I get exactly the same outcome. Does this help clarify the post?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: See above comment please

Comment: Clarifying comments are best put into the Question so that they're not overlooked or lost; thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller:I updated post

Comment: You still don't show us what's in `file` and what is `grep`ped for.

Comment: @RudiC: the file has various meta information and in a section a list of files is mentioned. Do you want the regex for grep? I am not sure I get what you are asking

Comment: Yes - the output of `grep -E regex file`.

Comment: @RudiC: the output is shown in the console as a list of file paths 
`foo/bar/a/b
foo/bar/c/d `
etc
After this I don't know if these are considered by bash as an array or a single string with new lines or how to diff with the output of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your arrays are named "array1" and "array2", bash code to check for equality:

```
equal=true
if [[ ${#array1[@]} -ne ${#array2[@]} ]]; then
    equal=false
else
    while IFS= read -r elem1 <&3; IFS= read -r elem2 <&4; do
        if [[ "$elem1" != "$elem2" ]]; then
            equal=false
            break
        fi
    done 3< <(printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | sort) \
         4< <(printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}" | sort)
fi
if $equal; then
    echo arrays have the same contents
else
    echo arrays have different contents
fi
```

This will be (probably "much") slower than calling out to external tools.

```
diff <(grep -E regex file1) <(grep -E regex file2)
```

Comment: How do I initialize the arrays? Also the 2 `<` in the `diff` snippet are they right?

Comment: Also what is 3 and 4?

Comment: "3" and "4" are file descriptors: I want to be able to read from 2 different files in the same loop, so I red them from different file descriptors. Note how `3<` after the loop corresponds with the `<&3` in one of the read commands.

Comment: The 2 < are correct: this bit `3<` is the [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Input) and this bit `<(...)` is a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

Comment: I can't make that part work. I get an error as if `diff` us using the outputs of `grep` as files and says can't open them